# El Capitan choking wifi speed on main user account

Tags: wifi, macos

I have spotted my wifi connection is being chocked to a much slower, yet steady, speed on my MacBook Pro (Retina, Mid 2012) running OSX 10.11.

If I login to a guest account it matches the wifi speed I experience on my iPhone 6s (145mbps up / 14mbps down).

I've turned off bluetooth, makes no difference. Rebooted the Virgin Media Superhub2 - no difference. Trashed prefs, cleared caches etc, same issue.

The only consistency is the capped/slower connection on wifi using my main user (14mbps down 6mbps up).

Any ideas?

Here's some monitoring info:

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help.

Avast Mac Security settings:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Which tool provides you the speed you wrote? Does it give you the speed used, the speed remaining or the total one (used+remaning)?

Comment: Do you happen to have any VPN software installed, such as Cisco AnyConnect? I've seen many complaints at work over decreased network speed (even when not connected to the VPN) after we were required to install AnyConnect vs. the built in VPN client.

Comment: Hi daniel - I was using http://www.which.co.uk/technology/broadband-tv-and-phone/guides/speed-test-your-internet-connection/ but get the same using speediest.net - both upload/download and then give a reading.

Comment: Hi Dave - thanks for the help. I have Avast Mac Security running. It does have a "Secure Line VPN" option but I don't have that enabled.

I will attach the settings under my original post.

Comment: Dave - I'm happy to uninstall Avast but would like a free mail scanner in place if possible (e.g. an alternative) - I do get the odd malicious email after my work address was harvested in the wild!

Comment: i have same problem as well. It is spotty too, It works for some time and doesn't work for some time. After some time it starts working again. Apple blamed service provider, proved that isn't case, I was having yosemite on different machine it works fine. Apple needs take some responsibility of bug